# I can't use the spinner function properly[kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm having trouble using the sendCommand function when the user change the spinner item to "Red":

```
class SetTrainingRouteActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_training_route)


        val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.S24)
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.A24,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            // Apply the adapter to the spinner
            spinner.adapter = adapter
        }

        S24.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

                if (S24.equals("Red")) {
                    sendCommand("1000024")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun sendCommand(input: String) {
        if (ControlActivity.arduino_bluetoothSocket != null) {
            try{
                ControlActivity.arduino_bluetoothSocket!!.outputStream.write(input.toByteArray())
            } catch(e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<string-array name="A24">
    <item>Off</item>
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
</string-array>
```

```xml
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/S24"
    android:textColor="@color/text_matrix_cell"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/A24" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading value in a wrong way. Below code will work

```
S24.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

    }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

        val selectedItem = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)

        if (selectedItem?.equals("Red") == true) {
            sendCommand("1000024")
        }
    }
}
```

What you are doing is comparing spinner instance to value "Red" which will never work, because they are not same.

You need to read the value using correct method and then compare them.

Comment: Android Studio is pointing a problem with

Object selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)

        if (selectedItem.equals("Red")) {
            sendCommand("1000024")
        }

Comment: If you could help me with that, I would really appreciate it

Comment: Android Studio is pointing these erros with the solution above

-Object classifier does not have a companion object and thus must be initialized here

-selectedItem unresolved referente

Comment: This is what I had to change.
override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                val selectedItem: Any? = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)
Thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah null safety, I updated my answer, with null safety